# Next js and Heroku application user when typed in is directed to http:// instead of the secure https://

Tags: heroku, next.js

in my first nextjs and heroku app i setup a payment page for my application, i upgraded my heroku dyno to have ssl automatically added and pointed a subdomain at my heroku app. all works fine but when a user manually types in the url for eg example.com they are directed to the http:// and not the https:// url which is bad because the payment portal wont work on a http://

If the user clicks on the url its goes to the according https:// url

Any help with this hopefully it's not a massive issue?

All the settings were set inside of heroku unless im missing a step in the setup process when pointing the domain let me know thanks legends!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to fall back to a custom `nginx` configuration. This can be done using `heroku-community/nginx` buildpack.

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku-community/nginx
```

And then create a config file for nginx at `config/nginx.config.erb` with something like this:

```
http {
  server {
    listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
    server_name _;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location / {

      <% if ENV['NGINX_SKIP_HTTPS_PROXY'] == 'true' %>
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
          return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
      <% end %>

      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; #next serve listens here and receives nginx requests
    }
  }
}
```

You will probably also want to turn on gzip and other settings. The full config file and more details are on [this post](https://pulkitgoyal.in/ssl-nextjs-deployment-on-heroku).